# macOS: Quit the program properly

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

If I click on the red symbol in the top left corner on Mac, the programs do not always close completely. In most cases I have to right click in the "Dock" and exit there. How can I set it so that I can close directly? (Without Shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

Use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Q</kbd>  for Quit.

Mac apps [unless they have only a single sheet] are designed to be multi-document capable.

This means that closing the last document does not quit the app, by design.

This is the antithesis of Windows' design, where each open document invokes a new instance of the app, so closing the document also closes the app.

You just have to get used to this paradigm.
Most apps also have a Quit item in the menu bar, linked to the Cmd/Q key command.

[Not all apps on either Mac or Windows behave *exactly* like this, but it is the paradigm from where they start.]